# create dictionary from excel cells in different rows and columns using python

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary that matches a project code to its corresponding Total cost value.  The values are in different rows and different columns.  However, there are other cells that can be referenced to get the values.  The excel sheet looks like so:

```
      A         B         C         D        E
1 Project    A1-234   Something  Something
2  does       not      matter
3 Total                                     1234
4
5 Project    A2-912   Something  Something
6  also       does     not        matter
7 another    will      not        matter
8 Total                                     789
```

The project code is the key and the total value is the value of the dictionary.  Based off of that, I would have 2 key value pairs:

```
dict = {
    "A1-234": 1234,
    "A2-912": 789
}
```

There are a lot of projects, but they all have these consistencies:

```
"Project":  Always in column A 
ProjectCode: Always in column B in the same row as "Project"
"Total":  Always in column A 
TotalAmount:  Always in Column E in the same row as "Total"
```

What is the best way of creating this dictionary ?

Comment: I can't imagine an easy solution for that, just a whole bunch of if statements. (eg. if row[0] == 'Project': key = row[1]; get_total = True )

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising. [xlrd and xlwt](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-python-parse-spreadsheet-data/)

I think I would use this to loop through the cells with regex and append to a dict. I'm new to python so this probably isn't a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

This technically works... If you know how to make the code prettier, please let me know.

```
from xlrd import *

# workbook containing the entire projects
wb = open_workbook("C:/Users/my.name/Documents/Projects.xlsx")
worksheet1 = wb.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

project_dict = {}
project_key_column = 1
total_value_column = 4
total_found = True
project_key = ""

# store the project key and Total value into a dictionary
for row_num in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
    # find a row with Ai=Project and set project_key to the key value next to it
    if worksheet.cell(row_num, 0).value == "Project":
        if not total_found:  # the total should be found before a second occurrence of Project
            print "WARNING: Project %s did not find a value row" % project_key
        project_key = worksheet.cell(row_num, project_key_column).value
        total_found = False  # find the value for the new Project key

    # find a row with Ai=Total and set the value in the G column to total
    if worksheet.cell(row_num, 0).value == "Total":
        total = worksheet.cell(row_num, total_value_column).value
        if total == "":
            print "WARNING: Project %s contains an empty Value" % project_key
        project_dict[project_key] = total  # add the key value pair of the project_key and total
        total_found = True
```